# When I enter aws-acess-id and aws-secret-key /: "ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. The security token included in the request is invalid:"

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, web-deployment, web-hosting

> When I enter aws-acess-id and aws-secret-key
> I tried different aws keys too
> generated from "labs.vocareum.com"
> It throws errors:  "ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. The security token included in the request is invalid:"
>
> Error

```
C:\Users>eb init -p python port-aws
You have not yet set up your credentials or your credentials are incorrect
You must provide your credentials.
(aws-access-id): ------(enter key from aws account)-------
(aws-secret-key): --------(enter key from aws account)----
ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. The security token included in the request is       
invalid.
```

> ReEnter

```
C:\Users>eb init -p python port-aws
ERROR: The current user does not have the correct permissions. Reason: Operation Denied. The    
security token included in the request is invalid.
ERROR: The current user does not have the correct permissions. Reason: Operation Denied. The  
security token included in the request is invalid.  
You have not yet set up your credentials or your credentials are incorrect
You must provide your credentials.
(aws-access-id): ------(enter key from aws account)-------
(aws-secret-key): ------(enter key from aws account)-------
ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. The security token included in the request is
invalid.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Educate does seem to allow Beanstalk:

- [AWS Services Supported with AWS Educate Starter Account](https://s3.amazonaws.com/awseducate-starter-account-services/AWS_Educate_Starter_Accounts_and_AWS_Services.pdf)

AWS Academy will also use `vocareum`, so similar limitations may apply.

However, all credentials that you get from `vocareum` are **temporary**. It seem to me that they have already **expired** for you. Thus you may need to **refresh** them by creating  new sandbox environment and getting new keys.

Comment: No matter how many times I refresh, I get the same error. Every time you open Vocareum's credential window, all three (id, key, token) are different. So there doesn't appear to be a way to use CLI. They allow BeansTalk in GUI, but I can't figure out how to even initialize a local environment (to view logs e.g.).